# Vmotion issues between hosts

Tags: cisco, vmware-esxi

Just added two new hosts to our infra, there is an issue with vmotion, the test vm moves over to the hosts no problem but I cannot ping or connect to the vm from outside vsphere once I move it too the new hosts.

The hosts are setup correctly from a storage point (as they migrate fine) but when I look at the networking side there are a lot less VLANS on the new network adapters.

We are using HP gen 8 servers mezzaine cards connecting to Cisco cbs3020 switches.

Vswitch

[image]

Vswitch 2 (can't ping vm)

[image]

Full Vlans on vswitch 2

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of the VMware vSwitch screen?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It turns out the mac addresses from the mezzanine cards on the HP blade chassis were not being seen on the router side, so we done a reboot of the physical Cisco switch last night and everything is now ok. I can ping out vm's that we move over.

Answer (score 4):

You need to have *equivalent* networking on both sides of the vMotion transfer. If the guest arrives on the new host and the requisite VLANs aren't present, it will lose its networking... That's exactly what you're describing.

Try to identify the VLANs needed by your VM and add them to the other hosts.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is right in front of you - the VM is currently on vSwitch port group VLAN63 on your first host. That doesn't exist on your second host. Networking must be *identical* for guest networks for networking to function after vMotion. Create a VLAN63 port group on your second host's vSwitch1

Comment: I've added the full vlans, vlan 63 is on the vswitch

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on the following hardware:

- M1000 Blade Chassis
- Dell MXL Force10 switch

The solution was to decrease the ARP table refresh rate on the Dell MXL Foce10 switch by issuing this command:

```
mac-address-table station-move refresh-arp
```